# Free up memory in GridView

Tags: android, memory, gridview

For an app I'm developing, I am trying to populate a GridView with a lot of images. To avoid OutOfMemoryExceptions, I check the amount of available memory and when a certain threshold is reached, I try to free up memory like so:

```
private void freeUpMemory() {
    // Clear ImageViews up to current position
    for (int i = 0; i < mCurrentPosition; i++) {
        RelativeLayout gridViewElement = (RelativeLayout) mGridView.getChildAt(i);
        if (gridViewElement != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridViewElement.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.getDrawable().setCallback(null);
            imageView = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that this does not actually free up memory. What I don't know is why. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you create your own ImageAdapter?  Does it implement GetView?  If so, freeing the images in the view passed to you as convertView would be the most effective way of managing your memory use.

Comment: setting imageView to null has no effect.  All you are doing is clearing your local reference.   If you call setDrawable on convertView, and you have no other references to the previous image, that should free the memory.

Comment: Yes I am using my own ImageAdapter with getView(). Every element in my GridView is a RelativeLayout containing an ImageView and a TextView. On the ImageView I use setImageBitmap. How would I free the images passed as convertView? It sounds promising, so could you give an example?

Comment: How would I set convertViews to zero for anything but the one at the current position in the GridView?

Comment: Since you do have an Image adapter, I'm going to convert these comments into an answer.

Comment: BTW you do not want to clear the image for any view that is still visible.  You'll get the getView() callback every time a new view is needed, and convertView will have an old, no longer visible, view if one is available.   There is a chance that there will be several no-longer-visible views if your images vary a lot in size.  I'm not sure how you can find those without also risking zapping a visible view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your ImageAdapter gets the "getView()" callback with convertView not null, it is telling you that this view previously supplied by the ImageAdapter is no longer visible on the screen.   That's a good time to recover the resources used by the view.   Something along the lines of:

```
 ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_in_grid_item);
 iv.setDrawable(null);
```

should remove the reference to the Drawable that is stored in the ImageView.  If there are no other references in your code to that Drawable it should be available for garbage collection.

Better yet, if you have another image to be displayed.

```
iv.setDrawable(newImage);
```

Then returning convertView as the new view to be used by the grid
will replace the old Drawable with a new one, removing the reference and potentially garbage collecting the image.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to the BitmapFactory.Options class of Android. It offers many controls on the Bitmap, and two are very interesting when dealing with a lot of images.

The best solution, I think, is to set **inSampleSize** to a value like 2 or 4. This will reduce the quality of the image, but will save a lot of memory. Try different values until you find a good ratio.

Sample from Android doc (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) :

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

There's also **inPurgeable**, allowing the system to use space from existing Bitmap, but you must be careful as it can leads to crash or invalid bitmaps.

Comment: My question was not how to reduce memory usage of an image. I already know how to do that. What I'd like to know is how to free up memory when an OutOfMemoryException is imminent since I can have essentially infinite images in my GridView.

Comment: Have you checked that there are no other references to the Drawable ?
Maybe Bitmap.recycle() can help.

Comment: Yes I tried that too, but it did not help :/ . Apparently those Bitmaps were already garbage collected automatically.